# How to make an API-key based REST call with Google Cloud client library

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, api-key, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to make an API call to Google Cloud Vision API using an API key from Golang. But I'm getting a `400: bad request, invalid_grant error`.

The apiKey/apiKeyOption part of the code below is mine.

What is the right way to make this call?  Is it possible at all?

```
import (
    // ...
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    vision "cloud.google.com/go/vision/apiv1"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func getImageLabels(filename string) []string {

    ctx := context.Background()

    apiKey := "..." // I have a valid api key generated in the console.
    apiKeyOption := option.WithAPIKey(apiKey)

    client, err := vision.NewImageAnnotatorClient(ctx, apiKeyOption)

    // ...
    labels, err := client.DetectLabels(ctx, image, nil, 10)

}
```

...

```
Failed to detect labels: rpc error: code = Internal desc = transport: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

Comment: I've now implemented this without the client libraries as a regular REST call.  But still interested to know if it's possible with the client libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to what I found in the official documentation (both in [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go#authorization) and [Golang documentation](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go)) of the Google Cloud client libraries for Golang, the current supported authentication methods are **Google Application Default Credentials** and **Service Accounts**, so there is no such option to authenticate using an API key.

However, as pointed out [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#api_keys), Google recommends using Service Accounts instead of API keys for security reasons, so I would suggest that you go with that option if you can.

> API keys can be used when calling Google APIs that don't require
>   authentication, and when using Google Cloud Endpoints. **For security
>   reasons, we recommend using service accounts instead**.

Answer (score 0):

@dsesto is right, it's always better to use a Service Account to authenticate. However, if you want to use an API key, it should work.

I've opened a [github issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/issues/252) on that library explaining the error.

The same request using curl works properly (no credentials):

```
curl https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<API_KEY>  -H'content-type:application/json' -d'{
 "requests": [
  {
   "image": {
    "source": {
     "imageUri": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"
    }
   },
   "features": [
    {
     "type": "LABEL_DETECTION"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}'
```